# Using OpenLayers Map as an Angular service

Tags: angular, typescript, openlayers, openlayers-6

I want to know if I you're aware of a way to use a service in Angular to create an OpenLayers map and pass that service to other components and update the map based on the interactions on those components. Below is my approach. I am not seeing the map on the screen, however, the Map object is being created when I log it.

**dashboard-map-service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Map, View } from 'ol';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DashboardMapService {

  map: Map;

  constructor() {
    this.map = new Map({
      view: new View({
        center: [16400413.444439406, -5295269.033843756],
        zoom: 12,
        minZoom: 10,
      }),
      layers: [
        new TileLayer({
          source: new OSM(),
        }),
      ]
    })
   }

   returnMap(){
    return this.map;
   }

   setMap(updatedMap: Map) {
    this.map = updatedMap;
    console.log("map", this.map)
   }
}
```

**add-location-component**

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Map } from 'ol';
import { DashboardMapService } from 'src/app/services/dashboard-map.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-location',
  templateUrl: './add-location.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-location.component.css']
})
export class AddLocationComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  refmap: Map;

  constructor(private dashboardMap: DashboardMapService) {
    this.refmap = dashboardMap.returnMap()
    this.refmap.setTarget("add-location-map")
    
    this.dashboardMap.setMap(this.refmap)
   }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {

  }

}
```

Comment: You must specify a `target` div in `new Map()`  The div must have also have a size set by style or css.

Comment: @Mike, I did try both but it does not work. It works when everything is inside of the  "add-location-component".

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, it was to do with the angular lifecycle hooks. Setting the target and value of the service map on ngAfterViewInit() did the trick. See the code below.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.refmap.setTarget("add-location-map")
    this.dashboardMap.setMap(this.refmap)
  }
```